# Can I build a NPC house out of Hellstone?

Tags: terraria

Can NPC homes be built out of Hellstone? Will they settle in? If they do, will they take damage?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they will move in. The only wall requirement is that it is solid. As with Spikes, NPCs do not take damage from contact with the Hellstone.

[image: Guide living in a Hellstone house]

Although Hellstone emits light, it doesn't count as a room's light source; hence the Torch.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not fond of the Guide.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I still haven't forgiven him for an act of high treason, so solitary confinement it is. Though in this case, I just wanted to make sure he does the teleporty moving-in thing that town NPCs do when nobody can see them. Also, so he wouldn't wander off again and invalidate the experiment.

Comment: dare I ask what treasonous act the fair-weather-friend committed?

Comment: @RavenDreamer It involved an accidental lava spill, an open door and a tidy sum of money that melted in aforementioned lava.

Comment: If you build the house on the ground with a lava-pit outside the door, he will constantly walk into it and die a horrible death, only to respawn and die again, for all eternity.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft A Sisyphean spawn point. I like it.