# Can NPC houses have two doors?

Tags: terraria

In [Terraria](http://www.terraria.org/) game, we can build houses for NPCs. They must be at least 8x5 from inside, and surrounded by walls and blocks. It must also have a chair, a table and a door.

But... Can it have two doors?

Two doors can be convenient, so we can access the house from either side, or even walk past it.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Terraria NPC houses only really care about the minimum requirements. You can go much grander if you'd like, for instance.

My Merchant actually lives in my dining room.

[image]

Three stories, two doors -- as long as it meets the minimum requirements, they'll move in. They [ain't picky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24877/can-i-build-a-npc-house-out-of-hellstone/24878#24878), either.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can.  I like for my houses to be symmetrical and so I always have a door on each side.  It works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, NPC houses may have any non-zero number of doors.

Comment: Negative doors?  Or did you mean to say any *positive integer number* :P

Comment: @Nick: I think he's saying they *require* a door, however, according to the image posted by Raven Dreamer, this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Nick T: I challenge you to build a room with a negative number of doors. I want to see this. :3

Comment: @richard marskell - drackir the house does have a door, it just happens to be on the bottom floor. The NPCs will still use a multi-story house, even though they can't navigate between the floors